# get sklearn.LabelEncoder() mappings after fit_transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get the mappings of label encoder to figure out which code got each string for a column in my df.

Here is the encoding code:

```
y[:]=LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y[:])
```

I would like to get something like this as output:

```
A:1
B:2
C:3
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should refrain from in-line initialisation if you want to be able to make use of the mappings or inverse-transformation later.

```
data = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B'] # `y`

le = LabelEncoder()
mapped = le.fit_transform(data)

mapping = dict(zip(le.classes_, range(1, len(le.classes_)+1)))
print(mapping)
# {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Better still, if you want to reverse the encoding, use `inverse_transform`:

```
print(le.inverse_transform(mapped))
# ['A' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'B' 'B']
```

Comment: Thanks coldspeed! Works perfectly.

Comment: Just wondering why using `range(1, len(le.classes_)+1)`? I thought it would start from 0, so shouldn't it be `range(0, len(le.classes_))`?